# Flutter different looks after build web

Tags: flutter, dart

after I build my Web App in Flutter the buttons and some other stuff looks different to my development version. But when I define exact the properties of a button then it works. I think he can't read the default properties, but I don't know im a stupid trainee developer :)

Maybe I have a wrong config in my Dockerfile:

```
RUN flutter clean
RUN flutter pub get
RUN flutter build web --no-tree-shake-icons --dart-define=PROFILE=prod
```

This is my developing version:
[image: dev version image]

This is my deploying version:
[image: deployed version image]

Im sorry, here is the call of my MaterialApp

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return BlocProvider(
    create: (context) => authenticationBloc,
    child: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      bloc: authenticationBloc,
      buildWhen: (previous, current) =>
          current is AuthenticationAuthenticated ||
          current is AuthenticationUnauthenticated,
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthenticationInitial) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return MaterialApp.router(
            title: profile?.config()["title"],
            theme: theme(),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            routerConfig: AppRoutes.routes);
      },
    ));
```

}

Comment: Including some code will be helpful.

Comment: Your generated build has silently added the "useMaterial3: true" property (its default true in the newer version of Flutter SDK). Could you share your MaterialApp Widget?

Comment: @DharamBudh I added the MaterialApp Widget Code :), im new on StackOverflow I don't know that you get the notification, when I edit my question